# How to query a different table and show values related to foreign key in Rails Application instead of hex values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models in my rails application.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item_type
end
```

and

```
class ItemType < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :item_type, :message=>"name cannot be blank!"
    has_many :items
end
```

While adding an item, I am getting the users to select the item type using a drop down selector.

```
<%= form_for(item) do |f| %>
  <% if item.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this item from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% item.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :item %>
    <%= f.text_field :item %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :item_type_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :item_type_id, ItemType.all, :id, :item_type %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

The view for index page of item is like this.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Items</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Item type</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.item %></td>
        <td><%= item.item_type %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', item %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Item', new_item_path %>
<%= link_to "Home", '/' %>
```

Now in this index page, I see the hex value of Item Type as shown in the image.

[image]

Instead of this hex code, I would like to pull the item_type (string) from the item_types table and display it in the index page for items.

Comment: by item_type (string) ... do you mean you want to display the class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<td><%= item.item_type.item_type %></td>`.
It looks weired but you will have to use this way since `item.item_type` shows the `ItemType` object and I think you want the actual `item_type` value from `ItemType` object so you will have to put the attribute name again i.e `item.item_type.item_type`.

To avoid confusion, you can rename the `item_type` column to something else(not to only `type`, that is reserved fro STI only.). Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it did the trick. Now I can see Item Type instead of hex value.

Comment: Good. But as I suggested, its better to not to keep a column name same as table name with underscore. It will create confusion like this case.Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question exactly what you want to display when invoking `<%= item.item_type %>`.

If you wish to display the class name then simply change it to:

```
<%= item.item_type.class.name %>
```

If you wish to display a particular property of item_type then simply invoke that property `item.item_type.item_type` for example.

Alternatively you can override `to_s` method to customise the output when invoking item.item_type

```
def to_s
  self.item_type
end
```

This can then be invoked as you are already doing so with:

`<%= item.item_type %>`

Comment: After rereading your question I realise you have item_type property for ItemType model, which caused me some confusion. I have amended my answer accordingly.